# Definition of Function

Tags: tag-removed, set-theory

What is authoritative canonical formal definition of function?

For example,

According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Function.html),
$$isafun_1(f)\;\leftrightarrow\;
\forall a\in f\;(\exists x\exists y \;\langle x,y\rangle = a)
\; \wedge \;
\forall x\forall y_1\forall y_2\;((\langle x,y_1\rangle\in f\wedge\langle x,y_2\rangle \in f)\rightarrow y_1=y_2))$$

According to Bourbaki "Elements de Mathematiques, Theorie des Ensembles",
$$
isafun_2(f)\;\leftrightarrow\;
\exists d\exists g\exists c\;(\langle d,g,c\rangle=f
\;\wedge\;isafun_1(g)\;\wedge$$
$$\;\wedge\;
\forall x(x \in d\rightarrow \exists y(\langle x,y\rangle \in g))
\;\wedge\;
\forall x\forall y(\langle x,y\rangle \in g\rightarrow (x \in d\wedge y\in c)))
$$

How to make agree definition of function as triple with extensional equality
$$
\forall f\forall g\;[\;(isafun(f)\wedge isafun(g))
\; \rightarrow \;
[\;(\forall x(\;f(x)=g(x)\;))\leftrightarrow f=g\;]\;]
$$
?

Why such divergences in definitions exist?

Upd: Two additional questions:

1. Why function is not a pair in $isafun_2$? First component of triple is perfectly derivable from the second.
2. What word `function` exactly means if no underlying theory is specified in context? If I build fully formal knowledge base about mathematics for automated reasoning and want to add notion of contextless function -- how I must describe it?

Comment: There isn't a divergence in the definitions. The definition you have copied down from MathWorld is not all that MathWorld writes - where is the "is uniquely associated with an object" part? That is the third clause in the "Bourbaki" definition you wrote, making the definitions agree.

Comment: To Dror Speiser:

I do not see any difference between $isafun_1$ and Wolfram's words.

"A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is such object that every $a\in A$ is uniquely associated with $f(a)\in B$. A function is therefore a many-to-one relation" means my $isafun_1$ statement plus two more:
$$dom(f,A)\leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A\leftrightarrow\exists y(\langle x,y\rangle \in f))$$
$$cod(f,B)\leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y(\langle x,y\rangle \in f\rightarrow y\in B)$$
Which clearly may be omitted because they are not part of `definition`.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding of the MathWorld definition. The two statements are part of the definition and may not be omitted.

Comment: To Dror Speiser: Do you really claim that `relation` is a triple, not set of pairs?

Wolfram: "A function is therefore a many-to-one relation".

Comment: The definitions are equivalent (but not "isomorphic"). $d$ is the domain and $c$ is the codomain in the second defnition, they are uniquely determined by $f$. Existensional does not hold for the second definition, since the codomain of $f$ may be bigger than $g$. I think the second definition is the right one. Especially in category theory, domains and codomains are important data for a morphism and a morphism should not be identified with some of its factors.

Comment: To Martin Brandenburg: The definitions are not equivalent because relation is not a triple. For the rest, I know all you mentioned and I also suppose that second definition is right one. But all questions remains unanswered.

Comment: I meant "equivalent" in the spirit of category theory. The answer, why there are different definitions, is simple: In analytical number theory for example, nobody cares for a fixed codomain for a function. But in other areas it may matter a lot: algebraic geometry, category theory, mathematical logic.  In fact, in some definitions of a category, it is required that $hom(x,y)$ are pairwise disjoint for different $(x,y)$.

Comment: To Martin Brandenburg: Give me a couple of examples, please, when fixed codomain matters a lot and just working with function range is not enough.

Comment: 1) Well, extensiona equality has then the form: $f=g$ iff $cod(f)=cod(g), dom(f)=dom(g)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in dom(f)$. I don't think this causes any problems. 2) Try to define "surjective" with the first definition.

Comment: To Dror Speiser: I've seen numerous sources that define function as in 1st case, not only MathWorld. For instance, http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/df-fun.html.

Comment: 
To Dror Speiser:
Do you understand that two definitions of prop

$$\forall a(prop(a)\leftrightarrow (...a...))
\;\wedge\;
\forall a(prop2(a)\leftrightarrow (..a..))$$

and

$$\forall a(prop(a)\leftrightarrow (...a...))$$

are exactly the same, if prop2 is not mentioned in first conjunct?


Comment: You're right, the definition in mathworld is just not the same as Bourbaki. Maybe you can send an email to update it, so that it would contain a formal paragraph with the second definition you wrote above,.

Comment: It seems to me that the words in Wolfram Mathworld (apparently unchanged after a decade) do not define ‘function’ at all but ‘function from $A$ to $B$’. That they later call $B$ ‘the’ codomain of $f$ lends support to this. Similarly, if somebody said ‘A subset of $A$ is a set $S$ such that every $a \in S$ belongs to $A$’, you would not think that they meant that ‘subset’ means the same as ‘set’. The superset $A$ is also part of the concept.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The fact is that different subject areas of mathematics use different definitions for this basic concept. The Bourbaki definition is quite common, particularly in many of the areas well-represented here on MO, but other areas use the ordered-pair definition.

For example, if you open any set-theory text, you will find that a function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs having the functional property that any $x$ is paired with at most one $y$, denoted $f(x)$. This definition, which is completely established and much older than the Bourbaki definition, makes a function a special kind of binary relation, which is any set of ordered pairs. The domain of a function is the set of $x$ for which $f(x)$ exists. The range is the set of all such $f(x)$, and so on. The assertion $f:A\to B$ is a statement about the *three* objects, $f$, $A$ and $B$, that $f$ is a function with domain $A$ having its range a subset of $B$. In particular, the same function $f$ can have many different codomains.

Another useful variation of the function concept is the concept of a *partial* function, common in many parts of logic, particularly set theory and computability theory. A partial function on $A$ is simply a function whose domain is included in $A$. In this case, we write $f:A\to B$, but with with *three* dots (my MO tex ability can't seem to do it), to mean that $f$ is a function with $dom(f)\subset A$ and $ran(f)\subset B$. This notion is particularly usefful in computability theory, where one has functions that might not produce an output on all input. But it also arises in set theory, where one often build partial orders consisting of small partial functions from one set to another. The union of a chain of such functions is a function again. It would be silly to insist in the Bourbaki style that there are really invisible functors running through this construction adjusting the domains and co-domains.

One could object that the set-theorists could use the Bourbaki definition, if only they prepared better: in any context where many functions are treated, they should simply delimit an upper bound for the co-domains under consideration and use that co-domain for all the functions. But this proposal bumps into set-theoretic issues. For example, if I consider the class of all functions from an ordinal to the ordinals, then the only common co-domain is the class of all ordinals. But as this is a proper class, it isn't available if I want to consider only set functions. So there are good set-theoretic reasons not to use the Bourbaki definition.

There are numerous other basic concepts that are given different precise meanings in different subjects of mathematics. For example, the concept of *tree*. In graph theory, it is a graph with no loops, whereas in set theory, it is a kind of partial order. In finite combinatorics, it might be a finitte partial order having no diamonds, but in the infinitary theory, one often means a partial order such that the predecessors of every node are well-ordered (making the levels of the tree form a well-ordered hierarchy). The graph-theoretic definition does not allow for the cases of Souslin trees and Kurepa trees, which are central in the other theory.

There are surely numerous other examples where terminology differs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, word function is meaningless if no underlying theory mentioned in context? If not, what meaning of this word is? 

Comment: For their most important uses, the two concepts are not so different---they share their most important feature, the functional relation between argument and value---and so outside of a definite context, one would still understand that part of the meaning. But I wouldn't take the union of a set of functions unless it was clear that I intended the set-of-ordered-pairs meaning.

Comment: The term "function" is not meaningless, but the precise definition has to be established by context. The same is true for many other words: "ring" (does it have a unity?), "poset" (weak, strong, or the same as a preorder?), "graph" (is it a simple graph?), etc. We lie to students by telling them that each term in mathematics has an authoritative definition, which doesn't stand up to close scrutiny. But it has an inner truth: the precise definition of "graph" may change, but it's not going to change into the definition of a ring. 

Comment: But I can't understand how we may use a word successfully if everybody will understand something slightly different from others while using it.

Can be that abstract contextless function defined in pure HOL as $$isafun(f)\leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y(x=y\rightarrow f(x)=f(y))$$?

Comment: How do you teach somebody contextless notion of function without resorting to handwaving?

Comment: Vag, there are of course degrees of precision in mathematics, each serving a different kind of purpose. At the bottom underlying level, there is the hyper-precise accounts arising in the various formal systems, which would be more precise even than the definitions you and I mentioned, but few would argue that we should all operate only in that formal language just because we believe that it is possible in principle to do so. 

Comment: I'm not talking about precision in communication or daily operation. I'm talking about precision and uniformity in *understanding* and *teaching*.

Comment: Vag, you are asking *how we manage to teach the concept of function*... just go into any class where it is taught, and you'll see that these problems you seem to be talking about simply do not exist.

Comment: Thanks all for replies, almost all questions answered perfectly.

But for the sake of honesty I must admit that all of you 1) do not know what contextless function is and 2) do not want to know.

Comment: It seems that Joel answer actually gives an example (the one with the ordinals) where one would need to use contextless functions. So your claim is a bit unfair, unless you mean something else for contextless function (you mean isafun_1, right?). Anyway, psychologically I feel much more at ease using the Bourbaki definition of a function, unless I'm forced not to do so by set theoretical issues.

Comment: No. Joel stated that isafun_1 is function in context of set theory and said nothing not vague about definition of contextless function.

Comment: So, _for me_ notion of contextless function remains meaningless.

Comment: Many words lack meaning out of context, while becoming precise in a context. Why should you expect that there is a meaning for this word outside of any context? Our various mathematical contexts are set up specifically to give words precise meanings, and there seems to be little reason why these contexts must agree. In the case of *function*, I took as my answer task to explain that indeed there is a difference in meaning for different subject areas. But we can all translate easily from one context to the other, and any amibguity is therefore quickly resolved. Is there any issue left?

Comment: With meaning in contexts we are done. But Carl Mummert said: "The term "function" without mentioning context is not meaningless". And it causes my asking: WHAT exactly is meaning of this word when NO context established? If this word without context is meaningless, there are no questions left. All clear.

Comment: I think Carl was referring to the feature, as we've mentioned, that there is a common core part of the various definitions, the crucial fact that we can evaluate a function to produce a single value at any point in the domain, on which all the definitions agree. So it would seem that the word function would carry at least this part of the meaning even when there is very little or no context. But I don't agree that it is required or even sensible for us to provide precise absolute context-free meanings for mathematical terms in the way you seem to desire.

Comment: In programming I've found that giving absolutely precise meaning for ANY terms is very rewarding. For instance, more rigour means more human activities to automatize or made computer assisted.

And while studying mathematics I've found that almost every time I formalize some important notion I discover various mistakes, misunderstandings, nontotalities, discrepancies, etc. Human intuition is good at abstracting and searching similarities but bad at case analysis.

Comment: But the function concept *has* been made absolutely precise. In fact, it has been made fully precise twice, in two different ways. Each group prefers to use their own precise definition, for sound reasons, and I don't see how it would help anyone for you to give a third, incompatible definition, that was different than either of these. Rather than giving a "contextless" definition, you would instead merely be providing a third, unneeded, context. 

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: In ambigious context (when it is unclear which known theory or which exact definition author uses) notion of function is indeed defined precisely (as 'isafun_1 or isafun_2 or logically equivalent'). Under 'contextless function' I mean not 'function in ambigious context' but precise meaning of word 'function' in heads of these who do not know neither isafun_1, nor isafun_2, nor their underlying theories but understands this notion perfectly.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: For example, every structure contains a (possibly empty) set of functional symbols so I guess there is notion of function that is completely theory agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

When we use the Bourbaki definition of function as a triple (domain, codomain, graph), then two functions are usually defined to be equal iff their domains and graphs are equal. So  equal functions can have different codomains. The problem is that the same sign "=" is used both for the  the equality of functions and the "universal" equality (In ZFC, for example, the "universal" equality is defined for all sets). That is, the sign "=" is overloaded. Normally, from the context one can determine what is the intended meaning.

But there is a more serious trouble (as Vag pointed out early) with the Bourbaki definition, when a function is an element of a set. So it seems that the  definition of function as a set of ordered pairs having the functional property is more preferable.

Comment: Let me devise some theory with contradiction in it. You'll come and see and state: "there is contradiction in it!". I'll reply: "No. This is misunderstanding on your side, because there is hidden patch that must be implicitly applied mentally while reading my theory, this patch removes contradiction completely." 

Comment: OK, I agree with your previous comment which you deleted. Then you asked about the case when a function is an element of a set. Indeed, in this case there is a serious trouble with the Bourbaki definition. So now in my work I decided not to use the Bourbaki definition.

Comment: Could you explain the *serious trouble* you mention? Why can't we have Bourbaki triples being elements of a set? This seems to happen quite often. 

Comment: Of course, Bourbaki triples can be elements of sets. But if we define the equality of functions as the equality of only their corresponding domains and graphs (but not codomains), then two functions may be equal, but the corresponding triples may not. The problem is, that when a function is an element of a set,  we may not know if a triple denotes a function or just a triple. So it will be a trouble with defining the equality of such sets.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with calling that relation equality, rather than a problem with the Bourbaki definition of function itself. Of course, it isn't really equality, but just an equivalence relation, whose equivalence classes are canonically indexed by the ordered-pair definition of function. But we have no reason to expect equality of sets to respect that relation.

Comment: Let me cite Y.Moschovakis from his "Notes on set theory", p.4:

"Two functions are equal if they have the same domain and they assign the same value to every member of their common domain".

When I googled "function equality", the first answer was:

"Two functions are equal if and only if they have the same domain and their values are equal at every point within the domain".

So it seems this definition of "function equality" is well accepted in ordinary mathematics.


Comment: Moschovakis uses the set-theoretic definition of function---the set of ordered pairs definition---not the Bourbaki definition. And for that definition, this notion of equivalence is equality.

Comment: @VictorMakarov I don't think that "Y.Moschovakis equality" is really well accepted. At least in topology.