# A question of terminology - Unitizations of semigroups

Tags: terminology, semigroups-and-monoids

There are at least two standard ways of unitizing a (small) semigroup $\mathbb A$:

(i) We add an identity regardless that $\mathbb A$ is already unital.

(ii) We add an identity only if none is already available.

In the former case, the unitization process is functorial, as it amounts to the existence of a left adjoint to the canonical forgetful functor from the category of small categories to the category of small semicategories (in the sense of B. Mitchell).

**Question.** Is there any standard terminology to differentiate (i) from (ii)? I would be content with something like "(i) is occasionally called the unitization *à la X*" or "(ii) is referred to by some authors as Y's unitization".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen (ii) called *the canonical unitization*.  

Comment: Actually the place I saw it was a well written paper whose author you may know: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3233 !

Comment: In the context of Banach algebras, (i) has sometimes been called the *forced unitization* and (ii) has been called the *conditonal unitization* -- I think I have seen this terminology in the pink book of Helemskii, for instance, but my memory is rusty.

Comment: I believe that there is no commonly used noun for these things.  I would call the process in (i) adjoining an identity and call the result A with an adjoined identity. Personally I would not give (ii) a name. I know of several results that are incorrect because people used (ii) in adapting monoid constructions to semigroups when they should have used (i). My book with Rhodes has a diatribe on this. 

Comment: In the context of rings, at least one former MO user (and former vocal MSE user) has referred to (i) as the *Dorroh extension* http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31358/can-a-mathematical-definition-be-wrong/31457#31457

Comment: @Yemon. OK, there is an analogy, but it's quite feeble, I think. I mean, I don't see any way to link the Dorroh extension, say ${\rm Drh}(\mathbb A,\mathbb M)$, of a unital ring $\mathbb A$ by a $(\mathbb A,\mathbb A)$-bimodule $\mathbb M$ to the unitization $\mathbb S^{(1)}$ of a certain semigroup $\mathbb S$, as defined by (i), in terms of the existence of a semigroup isomorphism between $\mathbb S^{(1)}$ and the multiplicative monoid of ${\rm Drh}(\mathbb A,\mathbb M)$ for an appropriate choice of $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb M$. If this isn't the case, then I wouldn't rely on such terminology.

Comment: _Addenda._ Even replacing, as would be reasonable, 'ring' with 'semiring' and 'bimodule' with 'bi-semimodule' in the phrasing of the previous comment.

Comment: @Salvo: I don't understand your previous comments. What BillD appeared to be describing was the left adjoint of the forgetful functor fom rings with unity to rings. As you observe, your (i) is the keft adjoint if the firgetful functor fom monoids to semigroups.

Comment: @Yemon. Yes, but this doesn't count for more than an analogy, _as far as I'm concerned_. That is, it is not enough _to me_ to justify the use of such terminology. I would use it only if something in the lines of what I wrote above may be true. But this doesn't seem to be the case.